# How can I rotate an Android textview with background color that is not jagged (needs to be anti-aliased)

Tags: android, textview, antialiasing

I have a static xml layout with a background color (looks like a printed label) that I want to show at an angle.  The issue I have is the edges of the background look like they were rendered in the 1980s (jagged - NOT anti-aliased).

How can I get a textview that looks like a label at an angle and have it look decent (i.e. anti-aliased)?

Layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Sample Text"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="#3db8eb"
        android:rotation="-3"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How it looks:

[image: Example]

Comment: You mean you want zigzag border of a `textView`?

Comment: No, I want a smooth border (anti-aliased) NOT a zig-zag jagged border like the picture shows.

Comment: Then you can use an image into the background.

Comment: Setting the background to an image (like a 9 patch) still doesn't work, the edges are still made jagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a few different things, I finally found something that works albeit a bit convoluted.  Here's how to get smooth edges on a rotated textview with a solid color background:

Step 1: Create a drawable resource with the color (i.e. ColorDrawable or Shape like a rectangle)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
</shape>
```

Step 2: Set the background to that drawable.

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/my_textview"
  ...
  android:background="@drawable/blue_rectangle" />
```

Step 3: In code call:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
textView.getBackground().setFilterBitmap(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

Per my [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41271365/178433), `setFilterBitmap` didn't quite work for me. Partially because I was using a 9patch background instead of a color.

### Approach #1: disable hardware acceleration on the view

What did work was disabling hardware acceleration for the view in question and its parent (either one, alone, did not work):

```
private void fixAntiAlias(View viewFromThe80s) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) {
        Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
        viewFromThe80s.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, p);
        ((View) viewFromThe80s.getParent()).setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, p);
    }
}
```

---

*edit: [2/2/17] : I ran into this problem again but this time needed to fix it only via resource file differences, rather than code/logic differences*

### Approach #2: XML-based fix

Sometimes, you don't have the luxury of editing the view logic. For instance, in my case, two views share the same RecyclerView.Adapter and one has a rotated view and the other doesn't. I need the view/adapter logic to remain unchanged but the XML layouts and resources can diverge. So I took this approach:

**1. Make a shape with a transparent border**
*src/main/res/drawable/background_rotatable_color.xml*

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- transparent 1px border -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <size android:width="16dp" android:height="16dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- main color : inset by 1px so the transparent layer below shows so that when antialiasing is done, it blends better -->
    <item android:top="1px" android:right="1px" android:left="1px" android:bottom="1px">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**2. Apply shape and (optional): use tinting to set it to desired color**
*src/main/res/layout-land/item_product_details.xml*

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_savings_banner"
    . . .
    android:background="@drawable/background_rotatable_color"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/blue_accent" /> <!-- optional but handy if you need to do this in a lot of places with different colors -->
```