# Android View setRotation causes artifacts

Tags: android, view

If I set the rotation to a view, there will be some artifacts on the margin of the view. [image]

How can I fix this?

I use `view.setRotation`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to enable anti-aliasing. If you're using Paint to draw on a Canvas, you can achieve this by calling `Paint.setAntiAlias(true)`. However, if you're drawing a Bitmap, you need to [set a 1px transparent border around your Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730249/canvas-antialiasing-with-hardware-acceleration-android-api-11-and-later)

Answer (score 0):

setAntiAlias is no longer working and turning off the acceleration mode would bring a disaster to most of the apps, so I propose a bit tricky solution:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        RenderEffect offsetEffect =
                RenderEffect.createOffsetEffect(0f, 0f);
        view.setRenderEffect(offsetEffect);
    }
```

Just use offset render effect with 0,0 values. It would do the job